# Unexpected unit "ms" unit-allowed-list, react scss

Tags: reactjs, sass

I am getting this error  `Unexpected unit "ms"   unit-allowed-list` while trying to commit the code. Errors is like below

```
 31:24  ✖  Unexpected unit "ms"   unit-allowed-list
 42:25  ✖  Unexpected unit "ms"   unit-allowed-list
 43:22  ✖  Unexpected unit "ms"   unit-allowed-list
```

**While css code between line `30 to 45` is**

```
&__Burst {
 animation: growSvg 1800ms ease-in-out forwards;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 6rem;
 margin: auto;
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 12;
}

&::after {
 animation: scaleOut 1400ms linear forwards;
 animation-delay: 400ms;
}
```

What is issue ? Thanks.

Comment: Ashwani, if you want to post your config file, either edit the question or post it as a comment. Don't edit it into an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a style config file in root folder named `.stylelintrc.js`. I just added `ms` in this config and all set.

```
 'unit-allowed-list': ['fr', 'rem', 'px', '%', 's', 'ms', 'em', 'deg', 'vh', 'vw']
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the unit to your allowed unit list:
https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/list/declaration-property-unit-allowed-list

```json
{  
...
    "animation-delay": ["s", "ms"]
...
}
```

Or for all `animation-*` rules:

```json
{  
...
    "/^animation/": ["s", "ms"]
...
}
```